# getting status code 400 for linkedIn login in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, linkedin-api

I have successfully logged in with matched email and password but when I tap on "allow" button after login, the request gives me status code : 400 and I can not move further. please help. Below is my code.

```
-(void)requestForAccessToken:(NSString *)authorizationcode
{
     NSString *grantType = @"authorization_code";
     NSString *strUrl = @"http://abc.xyz/home/demo1";
     NSString *redirectURL = [strUrl stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet]];

     NSString *postParams = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"grant_type=%@&code=%@&redirect_uri=%@&client_id=%@&client_secret=%@",grantType,authorizationcode,redirectURL,linkedInKey,linkedInSecret];

     NSData *postData = [postParams dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

     NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
     NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];
     NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:accessTokenEndPoint]];
     request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
     request.HTTPBody = postData;
     [request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

     NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
    long statuscode = [httpResponse statusCode];

    if (statuscode == 200) {
            NSMutableDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSReadOnlyDocumentAttribute error:&error];
            NSString *accesstoken = [dataDictionary valueForKey:@"access_token"];
        NSLog(@"accesstoken %@",accesstoken);

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:accesstoken forKey:kAccessToken];

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        });
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"wrong status code");
    }
}];

 [task resume];
}
```

I am referring this tutorial http://www.appcoda.com/linkedin-sign-in/, and converting code to objective C.

Comment: Hi. See - [LinkedIn OAuth](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2). You should send a `GET` http-request, not a `POST`.

Comment: Or possibly you create a wrong url-encoded `postData`. See this for example [URLEncodedStringValue](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFURLRequestSerialization.m)

Comment: @krutika were you able to solve the problem. I am facing the same issue?

Comment: Yes. I was entering wrong credentials. I have entered the same credentials for login with which I have created account in console and it worked.